# ViewPager and DepthPageTransformer

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I'm using ViewPager with DepthPageTransformer through the Support Library and everything was working just fine until I upgraded to the latest version of Support Library (18).

The DepthPageTransformer can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Now the problem I have is that Google has modified the ViewPager somehow, so that the DepthPageTransformer no longer works correctly.

When I add a Fragment to the ViewPager and the Activity that holds the ViewPager is recreated, the DepthPageTransformer seems to set the alpha to zero, and nothing shows up until I drag the ViewPager. After dragging, the ViewPager works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I simply removed the if clauses altogether at it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is tested and works fine:
First of all I use [nineoldandroids](http://nineoldandroids.com) library for lower 8 level apis.

```
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.PageTransformer;

import com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper;

public class DepthPageTransformer implements PageTransformer {
    private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;

    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
    int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

    if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
        // This page is way off-screen to the left.
        ViewHelper.setAlpha(view,0);

    } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
        // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
        ViewHelper.setAlpha(view,1);
        ViewHelper.setTranslationX(view,0);
        ViewHelper.setScaleX(view,1);
        ViewHelper.setScaleY(view,1);

    } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
        // Fade the page out.
        ViewHelper.setAlpha(view,1 - position);

        // Counteract the default slide transition
        ViewHelper.setTranslationX(view,pageWidth * -position);

        // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
        float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
        ViewHelper.setScaleX(view,scaleFactor);
        ViewHelper.setScaleY(view,scaleFactor);

    } else { // (1,+Infinity]
        // This page is way off-screen to the right.
        ViewHelper.setAlpha(view,0);
    }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use nineoldandroid just write `view.setAlpha(0)` instead of `ViewHelper.setAlpha(view,0)` and so on with scaleX, scaleY and translation.